# Parsing a Japanese website

Tags: r, parsing, encoding, web-scraping, html-parsing

I wish to parse some data on Tokyo house sales from a Japan website. 
The code are listed as follows:

```
library(XML)
library(bitops)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)

orgURL1 = 'http://www.stepon.co.jp/search/list/?pageNo=2&limit=100&prefCityCd=13_101&prefCityCd=13_103&prefCityCd=13_102&prefCityCd=13_104&prefCityCd=13_113&prefCityCd=13_105&prefCityCd=13_116&prefCityCd=13_117&prefCityCd=13_119&prefCityCd=13_108&prefCityCd=13_107&prefCityCd=13_106&prefCityCd=13_118&prefCityCd=13_123&prefCityCd=13_121&prefCityCd=13_122&prefCityCd=13_109&prefCityCd=13_110&prefCityCd=13_111&prefCityCd=13_112&prefCityCd=13_114&prefCityCd=13_115&prefCityCd=13_120&hanbaiKakakuMin=&hanbaiKakakuMax=&senyuMensekiMin=&senyuMensekiMax=&tohoTime=&chikunensu=&chijoKaiso=&souKosu=&floor=&mansionNm=&searchType=area&prefCd=13&type=mansion'

pttURL <- paste(orgURL1)
urlExists <- url.exists(pttURL)

alldata = data.frame()

html <- getURL(pttURL)
xml <- htmlParse(html, encoding = 'jis')

allinfo = xpathApply(xml,"//*/div/div/dl[@class='clearfix']",xmlValue)

tempdata = cbind(allinfo)
alldata = rbind(tempdata)
```

But the data parsed are shown in some unreadable characters, listed as follows:

```
> head(allinfo)
[[1]]
[1] "i\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1,500~\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

[[2]]
[1] "Yn\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ts`aOaXU\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

[[3]]
[1] "eE\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tgcacuuTOavwaeka3agcacuuOavwaeka9aguaJuuZ{Ovwaeka9a\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

[[4]]
[1] "Oae/eLEI\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[\xc2\u0080 / 20.46m簡\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

[[5]]
[1] "YKiuj\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1Kaij/na6KA\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

[[6]]
[1] "zN\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1977N05z\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

I guess it should be related to the encoding but I have tried 'shift-jis' and it didn't work.

I am new in parsing...
Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: To properly format your code, select the entire block and press the `{}` button in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the specify the encoding in rcurl parameter.

```
html <- getURL(pttURL,.encoding='shift_jis')
xml <- htmlParse(html)
```

Otherwise the `html` input is the wrong String like
`<meta content=\"\u0090ç\u0091ã\u0093c\u008bæ,\u0092\u0086\u0089\u009b\u008bæ,\u0093\u008c\u008b\u009e\u0093s,\u0092\u0086\u008cÃ\u0083}\u0083\u0093\u0083V`
(Note it is not the raw binary data).

Of course you cannot get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your original to work even as far as you've got it, but here's a version ported to rvest:

```r
library(rvest)

orgURL1 = 'http://www.stepon.co.jp/search/list/?pageNo=2&limit=100&prefCityCd=13_101&prefCityCd=13_103&prefCityCd=13_102&prefCityCd=13_104&prefCityCd=13_113&prefCityCd=13_105&prefCityCd=13_116&prefCityCd=13_117&prefCityCd=13_119&prefCityCd=13_108&prefCityCd=13_107&prefCityCd=13_106&prefCityCd=13_118&prefCityCd=13_123&prefCityCd=13_121&prefCityCd=13_122&prefCityCd=13_109&prefCityCd=13_110&prefCityCd=13_111&prefCityCd=13_112&prefCityCd=13_114&prefCityCd=13_115&prefCityCd=13_120&hanbaiKakakuMin=&hanbaiKakakuMax=&senyuMensekiMin=&senyuMensekiMax=&tohoTime=&chikunensu=&chijoKaiso=&souKosu=&floor=&mansionNm=&searchType=area&prefCd=13&type=mansion'

html <- read_html(orgURL1)

text <- html %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*/div/div/dl[@class='clearfix']") %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE)

head(text)
#> [1] "価格\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t4,200万円"                                
#> [2] "所在地\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t東京都足立区島根４丁目"                 
#> [3] "交通\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t東武伊勢崎・大師線「西新井」駅より徒歩8分"
#> [4] "間取り/専有面積\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2LDK / 73.51m²"                
#> [5] "所在階（向き）\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1階部分（南）/地上10階建て"     
#> [6] "築年月\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2011年02月築"
```

What you see may be at locale-dependent, and obviously won't display properly if you don't have a CJK font available.

Comment: Hi, alistaire, thank you so much for help. As you suggested, I first downloaded and installed the CJK font (from https://www.google.com/get/noto/) into my PC (restarted PC as well), then I tried the code you posted above. But after I key in the command "> html <- read_html(orgURL1)", I got the following error message:  "Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x87 0x75 0x81 0x40 [6003]"... would you please give me some suggestions? Thank you. Kate

Comment: That's a pretty opaque error. You could try specifying the encoding. Or download the page with `httr::GET` and extract the HTML to be passed to `read_html` with `http::content`. No idea if it will work, but it might at least get you a more meaningful error message.

Comment: Also, as I alluded to in the answer, check your locale (`Sys.getlocale()`). On Mac/Unix-alike any UTF-8 flavor is fine. Windows is different.

Comment: Hi, alistaire, thank you for the further info. I tried "Sys.getlocale()", and get the follows      [1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950;LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950"]         And I further want to set it into UTF-8 and I tried the code you suggested as follows: "Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = “UTF-8")", But I got the following error message: "Error: unexpected input in "Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = ?"    Any comments will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: UTF-8 requires a language/country variant, e.g. `ja_JP.UTF-8` or `zh_TW.UTF-8`. Yours look like Windows locales, though, in which case you might look [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930130.aspx) to figure out what you need.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will give it a try.